# Порошковый чай «Матча». Род слова

Tags: заимствования, названия, род

Само название чая, оканчивающееся на -а, нужно отнести к женскому роду или к мужскому? Как верно определить род?

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос на самом деле не так тривиален, как может показаться.
Слово словарями не фиксируется, поэтому можно только строить предположения на основании общих языковых тенденций. Хотя и здесь нет единых правил.

Да, наличие родового слова "чай" мотивирует использование нового слова в мужском роде, но это не императивное правило. При употреблении названия без родового слова имя собственное обычно сохраняет свой собственный род, а новозаимстванные имена собственные приобретают род по общим грамматическим правилам.

В нашем случае можно предположить, что со временем название станет женского рода - в соответствии со своими внешними признаками. Дело в том, что грамматически неодушевленные слова мужского рода, оканчивающиеся на ***-а***, в целом крайне нехарактерны для русского языка *(главным образом это образования с увеличительным суффиксом -ина: домина, голосина, холодина - причем большинство таких слов испытывают колебания в грамматическом роде: "жуткий холодина" и "жуткая холодина")*.

Таким образом, можно с некоторой уверенностью предпологать, что название при употреблении без родового слова осядет в русском языке в форме женского рода.

*Порошковая "Матча", вкусная "Матча"* - и проч.